# thread have same pririty..How to communicate between then

Tags: multithreading, process, communication

Consider there are 2 process and each process has 2 thread...say..A , B (first process) and C , D (second priority) all thse thread have same pririty.. how do you communicate b/w these thread..

Comment: Which programming language? Or are you looking for a theoretical answer?

Comment: The priority is mostly a red herring -- the same or different priorities is generally irrelevant (though some systems do have different mechanisms for real-time threads than for normal threads).

Comment: Hi Juhana, Jerry, you can assume C as programming language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inter-process communication is a large topic and the correct solution depends on the problem. Some of the most common inter-process communication methods are listed on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication), although you may want to read a good book on the subject.